# Why is C++ used in Android Studio (NDK)

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a question that why is C++ used in Android App Development, What Requirements aren't Full filled by Java or Kotlin so C++ Came to Picture.

Comment: mostly for games development

Comment: The Android documentation provide good reasons for native programming for Android - https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides.

Answer (score 1):

Android by itself is kind of linux system,   where app is run by davlik virtual machine (and byte code for it is compiled form java / kotlin).  Sometimes there is a need to be closer to operation system and develop in  native code  - say in C/C++.  NAtive parts of software have access to other APIs not available from davlik VM

Comment: Dalvik is a prehistory ;)

Comment: there are still dex files and runtime  though.

Comment: since android 5.0, Dalvik is called ART (Android RunTime)

Comment: It is more than a simple rename, dex files are compiled to machine code during app installation on target device, so that Android 5.0+ devices don't really run Java code.